# JPA does not return null value

Tags: java, jpa

I have a Student table in JPA which contains fields id(primary key), studentName and the studentCode from that studentCode is nullable. So in my table, some rows contains the studentcode and some are not. When i tried to get the studentCode from the Student table, only the studentCode which are not null are being returned and the null value student code is not returning. I googled this. But I can't find the correct solution.

I added the query such as

```
SELECT s.studentCode from Student s
```

and the studentCode of my table is `121,500,null,203,null,null` and so on. The query returns only the values of `121, 500, 203` and does not return the null value.

The datatype are for id(int), studentName(varchar(25)), studentCode(varchar(10))

Comment: What is `countryCode`? Shouldn't it be `studentCode` instead? and what is the datatype of that field?

Comment: @RAS Sorry, I wrongly typed that word

Comment: You can try adding condition `where s.studentCode IS NULL OR s.studentCode IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Can you show the complete code for the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add one where condition with not null property. Then it will return all values with null.
Ex:

`SELECT s.studentCode from Student s where s.pkid is not null`

Comment: Primary key will be always not null, specifying that in condition will not help.

Comment: Then try @NayanWadekar if its will not work i will post diff way which I'm trying..

Comment: @KanagarajM I given the query as SELECT s.studentCode from Student s where s.studentName is not null also. But still it does not return the null value of the studentCode

Comment: i am having the same issue. What was the exact solution.